# SSRS - Can't Delete or Manage Deployed Report

Tags: reporting-services, report, apostrophe, illegal-characters

I'd like to delete one of my deployed SSRS reports, then recreate it, but I can't.  When I click the report's "Manage" ellipsis on the Report Server I get this:

[image]

It's weird because the report works fine, both in the Visual Studio preview and after deployment onto the Report Server; I just can't "Manage" the report on the Report Server.  How can I delete this report from my Report Server?  I have tried deleting the entire folder containing the problematic report, then redeploying all of the reports, datsets, etc. but I still wind up with the same problem with this one report.

Comment: can you manage any of the other reports or is it is just one report? Do you have admin rights to do so?

Comment: Which browser are you using? IE works best when making changes to the report manager.

Comment: @Harry: it's just this one report.  I can manage (or delete) any of the other reports without any problems.  I have full admin rights on the report server.

Comment: @aduguid: I'm using IE11.

Comment: Have you tried to do the update directly on the report server?  e.g. remote to the report server then navigate to the report manager in IE.

Comment: Try deleting it directly from the catalog. When you deploy it again it might resolve the issue. Locate the record with `SELECT * FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog WHERE [Name] LIKE '%myReportName%'`. Delete the record, refresh the report web portal page to make sure it's gone then redeploy.

Comment: @aduguid: Yes, that's exactly what I've been trying to do.

Comment: Alan: Thanks for that suggestion.  I did as you suggested (first I deleted the FK record from `ReportServer.dbo.DataSource` then I deleted the `ReportServer.dbo.Catalog` record).  Checking the web portal confirmed it was gone.  I then redeployed the report and found the same error.  This tells me [I think] that there's something wrong with the report, which is odd because Visual Studio doesn't flag any errors, it runs fine in the VS preview, it deploys without any errors or warnings and it runs fine on the report server.

Comment: I redid the report as "Test Report.rdl"; deployed & and checked Report Server Manage ellipsis after each step.  Worked fine at every step. Deleted old report from server per Alan's suggestion, deleted "Test Report" from server, renamed "Test Report.rdl" to desired report name, previewed (worked fine), deployed renamed report and **SAME ERROR!!** Turns out I had an apostrophe in the report's name.  Remove it, redeploy and it's fine.  Sounds similar to [this Power BI issue](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/Apostrophe-in-Folder-Name-Causes-Menu-Failure/idi-p/304933).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your report have an ' in the name?  Or some other wild character?  SSRS will not be happy about it.

To fix this you'll have to go to the ReportServer database on which ever server it's deployed on.  Open the Tables folder and find the dbo.Catalog table.  Right click and edit 100 rows.  (or more)  Find the report that is causing the problem.  Change the name of the report in both the Name and the Path column and return.  Since your report now does not have the wild character in the name, you may manage it or delete it from the SSRS application.

Comment: Thanks Brian--that's exactly what I finally figured out; see my 18-Feb-2020 comment beneath my original post (it's the last of several comments that were entered back in February 2020.).  I'm marking yours as the correct answer in case anyone trips over the same issue.